# Is there any dependency between Spring and Apache Tomcat Jar

Tags: java

Following is the timeline of how i got error in my application

1. Used Spring 2.5.3 and tomcat 7.0.27 - No Error
2. Upgraded to Spring 3.1.1 with same tomcat (7.0.27) - No Error
3. Upgraded tomcat to 7.0.42, used with Spring 3.1.1 - VerifyError

When i stop my application, i get 1000 verifyerrors (seperate error for every destroyBean) when i upgraded to tomcat 7.0.42.

Following is the Stack Trace:

`java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/springframework/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryUtils, method: convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible signature: (Ljava/lang/RuntimeException;)Lorg/springframework/dao/DataAccessException;) Wrong return type in function
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:442)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:988)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:556)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

Possible Cause:
    **fixed EntityManagerFactoryUtils's "convertJpaAccessException" to always return rather than throw DataAccessExceptions**
      This line is in ChangeLog of Spring 2.5.6

But my application works fine with Spring 3.1.1 and tomcat 7.0.27 but throws this error when upgraded to tomcat 7.0.42

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Tomcat doesn't depend on Spring, and Spring doesn't depend on Tomcat.  Not in any version of either.

I suspect that in the intermediate version of your application after "upgrade to Spring 3.1.1 with same tomcat (7.0.27)", you either didn't trigger that code to be run.  Note that it is happening in code that is run when a webapp is shut.  If you never attempted a clean shutdown in the intermediate version of your application, that `postProcessBeanBeforeDestruction` method wouldn't be called on that bean, and the problem wouldn't arise.

My guess is that the real problem is caused by mixing versions of Spring JAR files.